# Why does TypeScript complain that a pop() from an array may return undefined, if the array’s type guarantees it is non-empty?

Tags: typescript

I have this piece of Typescript code defining a class:

```typescript
export class AtLeastOneOfCriteria<T> implements Criterion<T> {
  private criteriaList: [Criterion<T>, Criterion<T>, ...Criterion<T>[]]

  // at least two criteria are asked by the constructor here
  constructor (criteriaList: [Criterion<T>, Criterion<T>, ...Criterion<T>[]]) {
    this.criteriaList = [...criteriaList]
  }

  meetCriterion (items: T[]): T[] {
    const list: [Criterion<T>, Criterion<T>, ...Criterion<T>[]] = [...this.criteriaList]
    // the following variables are marked as 'Criterion<T> | undefined'
    const firstCriterion: Criterion<T> = list.pop()
    const secondCriterion: Criterion<T> = list.pop()
    let resultCriterion = new OrCriteria<T>(firstCriterion, secondCriterion)
    for (const criterion of list) {
      resultCriterion = new OrCriteria<T>(resultCriterion, criterion)
    }
    return resultCriterion.meetCriterion(items)
  }
}
```

I could not understand why ESLint (in VSCode) marks the following error on `firstCriterion` and `secondCriterion` variables

```text
Type 'Criterion<T> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Criterion<T>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Criterion<T>'.
```

With the design of the `AtLeastOneOfCriteria` class constructor, why does the `this.criteriaList` array have not at least two items in it? Why `this.criteriaList.pop()` could be `undefined` the first and second times?

I try to build a multiple criteria `Criterion<T>` class based on OR (there is a match when at least one of the criteria matches) so I need to be sure that the list of criteria passed as argument to my class constructor contains at least two elements for the `OrCriteria` object which needs two arguments to be built.

### Edit : have a look at @[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) last comment that solves the problem

Comment: TypeScript does not understand that `list` has at least two items at that point. When you invoke `Array.prototype.pop`, the type of `this` is simplified to `Criterion<T>[]`, and in the general case, an array is always allowed be empty. More generally, an ordinary static type checker like TypeScript’s does not understand state. A binding has a fixed type for its entire lifetime, where for your example to work, the type of `list` would have to change over time. (Consider what would happen if you had a third `list.pop()` call. Or passed `list` to some opaque function somewhere else.)

Comment: And even more generally: a type checker is never going to have full insight into your app logic. There will always be things that you can prove are true, but the compiler cannot; this is why statically types languages almost all have some feature for "trust me, this will be the state at this point".

Comment: "*I need to be sure that the list of criteria passed as argument to my class constructor contains at least two elements*" - actually, I don't follow that argument. You don't *have to* build an `OrCriteria` at all! If there's only one criterion in your `criteriaList`, just check the items to meet that one criterion. And you could even extend this to an empty criterion list: just return no items.

Comment: Btw, even if you needed at least two criterions, you should have to spread-clone the array and use `pop()` on it. Just use destructuring: `const [firstCriterion, secondCriterion, ...list] = this.criteriaList;`, that will be more efficient, get you the right types, and also get you the criteria in the correct order (`pop()` returns the *last* element of a list, not the first).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your advice, it solves all of my problems all at once!